# javascript loop on a array object that contain another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array object that contain an array i want to to loop on this array object to get all the information from it and all the information of the array in this array object

```js
const database = [
    {
        sectorName: "قطاع السياحة",
        sectorCode: "t102",
        sectorIcon: "fas fa-suitcase",
        sectorN: "tourism",
        info: ["ترخيص عقاري", "الارشاد السياحي", "تنظيم الرحلات السياحية", "حجز وحدات الايواء", "الايواء السياحي"],
        desc: "شرح تفصيلي",
    },
    {
        sectorName: "قطاع الصناعة",
        sectorCode: "K503",
        sectorIcon: "fas fa-map-marked-alt",
        sectorN: "industry",
        info: [],
        desc: "شرح تفصيلي",
    },
    {
        sectorName: "قطاع الزراعة",
        sectorCode: "B201",
        sectorIcon: "fas fa-suitcase",
        sectorN: "agriculture",
        info: [],
        desc: "شرح تفصيلي",
    },
    {
        sectorName: "قطاع التجارة",
        sectorCode: "m907",
        sectorIcon: "fas fa-map-marked-alt",
        sectorN: "trading",
        info: [],
        desc: "شرح تفصيلي",
    },
    {
        sectorName: "قطاع النقل",
        sectorCode: "P001",
        sectorIcon: "fas fa-suitcase",
        sectorN: "transport",
        info: [],
        desc: "شرح تفصيلي",
    },
];

function getInfo() {
    let href = document.location.href;
    let id = href.split('=')[1];
    console.log(id);
    for (let i = 0; i < database.length; i++) {

        if (database[i].sectorCode === id) {
            selectElement('.title').innerHTML += `${database[i].sectorName}`;
            selectElement(".left").innerHTML += `
<div class="box">
<div class="inner-box">
<div class="title"><a href="steps.html?id=${database[i].sectorCode}">${database[i].info[i]}</a></div>
<div class="desc">${database[i].desc}</div>
</div>
<a href="steps.html?id=${database[i].tId}" class="btn">اختار</a>
</div>
`;
        }
    }
}
```

with my code i can't access all the information inside the info array, i want to acces all the information plus the information inside the info array and print them each one in a div
how can i make it?

Comment: `href.split('=')[1]` is really fragile. Is that supposed to be a search parameter like `?id=t102`? Then please use `new URLSearchParams(location.search).get("id")` instead. Why are you doing `.info[i]`? How is `i`, the index of the `database` entry, related to the entries of `info`?

Comment: thank you i did it let href = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search);
    let id= href.get("id");

Comment: Though `href` is a misnomer. A search parameter object is not a hyper reference.

Comment: i changed it let parms = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search);
    let id= parms.get("id");

Comment: @SebastianSimon can you please help me to print the result like that mhmd2991.github.io/projectTest/sector.html?id=t102

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array.join` to create a string from an array. `array.join(",")` inserts commas between the elements of the array.

If you want to do something significantly more complicated, I would recommend using a second for loop for the `info` field.

Example:

```js
const database = [
    {
        sectorName: "قطاع السياحة",
        sectorCode: "t102",
        sectorIcon: "fas fa-suitcase",
        sectorN: "tourism",
        info: ["ترخيص عقاري", "الارشاد السياحي", "تنظيم الرحلات السياحية", "حجز وحدات الايواء", "الايواء السياحي"],
        desc: "شرح تفصيلي",
    },
    {
        sectorName: "قطاع الصناعة",
        sectorCode: "K503",
        sectorIcon: "fas fa-map-marked-alt",
        sectorN: "industry",
        info: [],
        desc: "شرح تفصيلي",
    },
    {
        sectorName: "قطاع الزراعة",
        sectorCode: "B201",
        sectorIcon: "fas fa-suitcase",
        sectorN: "agriculture",
        info: [],
        desc: "شرح تفصيلي",
    },
    {
        sectorName: "قطاع التجارة",
        sectorCode: "m907",
        sectorIcon: "fas fa-map-marked-alt",
        sectorN: "trading",
        info: [],
        desc: "شرح تفصيلي",
    },
    {
        sectorName: "قطاع النقل",
        sectorCode: "P001",
        sectorIcon: "fas fa-suitcase",
        sectorN: "transport",
        info: [],
        desc: "شرح تفصيلي",
    },
];

function getInfo() {
    let href = document.location.href;
    let id = href.split('=')[1];
    console.log(id);
    for (let i = 0; i < database.length; i++) {

        if (database[i].sectorCode === id) {
            selectElement('.title').innerHTML += `${database[i].sectorName}`;
            selectElement(".left").innerHTML += `
<div class="box">
<div class="inner-box">
<div class="title"><a href="steps.html?id=${database[i].sectorCode}">${database[i].info.map(curr => `<div>${curr}</div>`)}</a></div>
<div class="desc">${database[i].desc}</div>
</div>
<a href="steps.html?id=${database[i].tId}" class="btn">اختار</a>
</div>
`;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but i want to print them each one on a div not all of them in the dame div

Comment: @user3018000 I've updated it so it should suit your needs now

Comment: thank you for your help but i want the result to appear like that https://mhmd2991.github.io/projectTest/sector.html?id=t102 and in the code it's not the same result

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` and `join` to achieve it:

```
`<div class="info">${database[i].info.map((inf) => '<div>' + inf + '</div>').join("")}</div>`
```